# Why does a Gulf Coast campus need an active steam network?

Tags: civil-engineering, heating-systems

The other day, some restauraunts in the union were closed "due to steam outage." I had seen the venting of course, but had thought little about why the school has a steam system. As best I can find, steam is usually used for heat distribution from a central heat plant; more efficient, etc. But the average yearly low temperature here is 57 degrees. What purpose does the system serve?

Comment: Steam has multiple uses..more than just heating. It is even used for cooling! This popped into my head: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_City_steam_system#Uses I’m sure there are more uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steam networks are used for heating (there are still heaters in use on the gulf coast), creating hot water, and any other energy loads a university might need.  I suspect that the restaurants in question didn't have hot water.